# DC2Type:array comment being added to field when doing a Doctrine migration diff

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

When I run `doctrine:migrations:diff` I have a unexecuted migration relating to a table and entity that I have not made changes to.

This is the SQL that is generated:

```
ALTER TABLE crmpicco_course_guide_row CHANGE courses courses 
LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:array)\'
```

This is the original SQL generated when mapping the entity and creating the table for the first time:

`courses LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL`

My Doctrine mapping:

```
    courses:
        type: array
        nullable: true
```

My entity:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $courses = array();

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCourses()
{
    return $this->courses;
}

/**
 * @param array $courses
 */
public function setCourses(array $courses)
{
    $this->courses = $courses;
}
```

Why is it adding the comment and is there a way to prevent this from appearing during a `diff`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment is added [because of this method](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ArrayType.php#L77):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return true;
}
```

You can overwrite the existing class and use your custom class where you return false:

```
<?php

namespace My\DBAL\Types;

/**
 * Overwrite array type to prevent comment hint
 */
class ArrayType extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And register your custom type as follows:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    // ...other config

    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'types' => array(
                'array' => 'My\DBAL\Types\ArrayType'
            )
        )
    )
)
```